# How can fill characters in sed only

Tags: sed

I have this file. I want to use only sed, no awk

```
FSDFDSFSD
FDSFD
FHGDHFDHGHFGHGHGF
HHGDF
GFDGDFGFDG
GFDGFDGFDGDFGDGD
```

I want to fill every odd line appended with 000 so that total characters are 30 in each line

I want output like

```
FSDFDSFSD0000000000
FDSFD
FHGDHFDHGHFGHGHGF00
HHGDF
GFDGDFGFDG000000000
GFDGFDGFDGDFGDGD
```

Answer (score 6):

One way:

```
sed -e :a -e 's/^.\{1,29\}$/&0/;ta' -e n file
```

Match any character(.), and match 1 to 29 characters of the same type(1,29). If match successful, put a '0' behind the pattern matched(`&`). When the match fails which means when the count of characters excluding the first character exceeds 29, stop it and hence we get the string zero padded by 30.

`n` at the end simply reads the next line and prints it. This way the even numbered lines get printed untouched.

Executing the above script:

```
$ sed -e :a -e 's/^.\{1,29\}$/&0/;ta' -e n file
FSDFDSFSD000000000000000000000
FDSFD
FHGDHFDHGHFGHGHGF0000000000000
HHGDF
GFDGDFGFDG00000000000000000000
GFDGFDGFDGDFGDGD
```

Comment: Its not working , it completely removed the other characters and fill the line with zeroes only

Comment: it works fine for me, added the output above..

Comment: I get this as ouput `00000000000000000000
FDSFD
000000000000HGHGF
HHGDF
0000000000000000000
GFDGFDGFDGDFGDGD`

Comment: @user1544681: I'm guessing you need to convert your file to have unix line endings.

Comment: i tried everything but same. can you give me some sample file where it works , so that i can copy paste that in vm

Comment: @user1544681: run `file` on the file, if it says something like: "ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators", you have MS line endings. You can use the `dos2unix` tool to change that or [vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format) if you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach:

```
sed 's/$/000000000000000000000000000000/;s/\(.\{30\}\).*/\1/;n'
```

That would be faster than the iterative approach at appending one character at a time, but note that it would truncate lines that were longer than 30 characters in the first place.